# How to change and continuously update RealityKit's Text using a keyboard?

Tags: swiftui, scenekit, realitykit, arview

I have been able to do this on SceneKit in the past for whatever reason this can't be done on RealityKit. This is some code I am using to test before adding to the app I am working on.

## Updating AR Text from Header View text

So I have a header view and the header view updates the text as I type in new text. The problem is, it can't update the AR text inside ARView.
In the image below, on the left you can see the header view matches the ARText. This is what you see initially on the screen.

The issue is the data is not updating continuously. The code already made the original text update to the header text once it runs, but it is not updating once with keyboard has changed the header text.

HOWEVER once I change the header text using my keyboard ( Image on the right ), **the text does not update on the AR View**

[image]
[image]

I know the problem is I can't add the dollar sign $title or $title input in the way I do elsewhere which works.

For example here under Content View,
**clicking on the header text allows me to successfully change the text ( on the header view only ).**

## Content view - changing header text works

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit


struct ContentView : View {
    
    @State var title: String = "Default Title"
    @State private var titleInput: String = ""
  
    var body: some View {
        // Button on top of the screen
        
        VStack { HeaderView(title: $title)
            
            TextField("Insert Title", text: $titleInput)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            Button(action: {
                title = titleInput
                titleInput = ""
            }, label: { Text("Change Title")})
            //Spacer()
        }//.padding()
        
        // AR screen space
        
        
        ARViewContainer(title: $title, titleInput: $titleInput).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        
    }
    
    
}
//end of content view struct


//another view here as the header view
struct HeaderView: View {
    @Binding var title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(title)
        //.padding(10)
    }
}
```

## ARView:

### The text successfully updates from the initial header view text, as per initial code below which is nice but not the final solution I seek, where AR text is constantly update by the keyboard.

Perhaps some of you might know the way around it.
I will add what worked for me using scene kit in a bit.

```
//AR View Container
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var title: String
    @Binding var titleInput: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        //AR View Begins
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        
        //AR Content
        // Load the "Box" scene from the "Experience" Reality File
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
        
        // Add the box anchor to the scene
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
        
        
        let boxImg = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: simd_make_float3(0.03, 0.01, 0.02)))
        if let texture = try? TextureResource.load(named: "texture") {
            var imageMaterial = UnlitMaterial()
            imageMaterial.baseColor = MaterialColorParameter.texture(texture)
            boxImg.model?.materials = [imageMaterial]
        }
        
        
        
        
        //end here what to bring to texture app starting above
        
        let text = MeshResource.generateText(title,
                                             extrusionDepth: 0.1,
                                             font: .systemFont(ofSize: 0.1),
                                             containerFrame: .zero,
                                             alignment: .center,
                                             lineBreakMode: .byWordWrapping)
        
        let shader = UnlitMaterial(color: .yellow)
        let textYellowEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: text, materials: [shader])
        textYellowEntity.position = simd_make_float3(-0.1, 0, -0.7)
        
        
        let textEntity = Entity()
        textEntity.setText("Please Update")
        
        //textYellowEntity.setText(title)
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.addChild(boxImg)
        anchor.addChild(textYellowEntity)
        anchor.addChild(textEntity)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        //End of AR Content
        
        return arView
        //AR View Ends
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
    
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

## Extensions

```
extension Entity{
    
    /// Changes The Text Of An Entity
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - content: String
    func setText(_ content: String){ self.components[ModelComponent] = self.generatedModelComponent(text: content) }
    
    /// Generates A Model Component With The Specified Text
    /// - Parameter text: String
    func generatedModelComponent(text: String) -> ModelComponent{
        
        let modelComponent: ModelComponent = ModelComponent(
            
            mesh: .generateText(text, extrusionDepth: TextElements().extrusionDepth, font: TextElements().font,
                                containerFrame: .zero, alignment: .center, lineBreakMode: .byTruncatingTail),
            
            materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: TextElements().colour, isMetallic: true)]
            
        )
        
        return modelComponent
    }
    
}

//--------------------
//MARK:- Text Elements
//--------------------

/// The Base Setup Of The MeshResource
struct TextElements{
   
    
    let initialText: String = "cube"
    let extrusionDepth: Float = 0.01
    let font: MeshResource.Font = MeshResource.Font.systemFont(ofSize: 0.05, weight: .bold)
    let colour: UIColor = .white
    
}
```

## For reference, what worked for me in the past, using SceneKit

#### SceneKit updated the ARtext when I used inputText on the screen, as you can see below.

The ARtext updates as soon as I enter the text on the textfield

[image] [[image: SceneKit screenshot3]

```
  @IBOutlet weak var inputText: UITextField!
```

```
   @IBAction func updateAct(_ sender: Any) {
        sceneView.removeNodeByName(nodeName: "flyingText")
        sceneView.add3DText(showText: self.inputText!.text! ,nodeName: "flyingText")

        
        }
```

```
       // Set a delegate to track the number of plane anchors for providing UI feedback.
        sceneView.session.delegate = self
        sceneView.add3DText(showText: self.inputText!.text! )
```

#### extension

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import SceneKit

extension ARSCNView {
    
    func removeNodeByName(nodeName: String)  {
        self.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
            if node.name == nodeName {
                node.removeFromParentNode()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func add3DText(showText: String, nodeName: String = "flyingText")  {
        let inText = showText.isEmpty ? "Text not Avaiable!" : showText
        let text = SCNText(string: inText, extrusionDepth: 0.9)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        //material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: randomMaterial())
        text.materials = [material]
        
        let node = SCNNode()
        let xpos = randomPosition(lowerBound: -0.5, upperBound: 0.5)
        let ypos = randomPosition(lowerBound: -0.5, upperBound: 0.5)
        node.position = SCNVector3(x: -0.5, y: -0.5, z: -0.3)
        //referenceNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0.01,0,0,.pi/2)
        node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0.01,0,0,0)
        node.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.01, y: 0.01, z: 0.01)
        node.geometry = text
        //node.name = nodeName
        node.name = nodeName
        
        self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        //self.allowsCameraControl = true
        self.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
    
    }
    
    
    
    func randomPosition ( lowerBound lower:Float, upperBound upper:Float) -> Float {
        return Float(arc4random()) / Float(UInt32.max) * (lower - upper) + upper
    }
    
    
    
}
```

## Update, we have the solution:

### AS USUAL Andy Jazz's answer ( see his answer and code below ) works!!!

Here's the screenshots to prove it: Before and After inputting next text

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to achieve, even though the code is quite simple. I just copy-pasted this code from my recent project. Unfortunately I have no free time at the moment to adapt my code to your project. But everything works fine 100%.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    @State var title: String = "Default Title"
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var entity = ModelEntity()
    @State var mesh = MeshResource.generateText("")
    @State var bool: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .frame(alignment: .center)
                .font(.title)
            
            TextField("Enter text here:", text: $text)
                .padding([.horizontal], 20)
            
            Button("Change title") {
                if text != "" {
                    bool.toggle()
                    title = text
                    mesh = MeshResource.generateText(title,
                                      extrusionDepth: 0.01,
                                                font: .systemFont(ofSize: 0.12))
                    entity = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh,
                                    materials: [UnlitMaterial(color: .cyan)])
                    let xHalf = mesh.bounds.extents.x / 2
                    entity.position.x -= xHalf
                    text = ""
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                    bool.toggle()
                }
            }

            ARViewContainer(arView: $arView, title: $title,
                                            entity: $entity, bool: $bool)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .onAppear {
                    bool.toggle()
                    mesh = MeshResource.generateText(title,
                                      extrusionDepth: 0.01,
                                                font: .systemFont(ofSize: 0.12))
                    entity = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh,
                                    materials: [UnlitMaterial(color: .yellow)])
                    let xHalf = mesh.bounds.extents.x / 2
                    entity.position.x -= xHalf
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                        bool.toggle()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var arView: ARView
    @Binding var title: String
    @Binding var entity: ModelEntity
    @Binding var bool: Bool
    var anchor = AnchorEntity()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        if bool {
            anchor.addChild(entity)
            anchor.position.z = -1.0
            arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        }
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ arView: ARView, context: Context) {
        if bool {
            arView.scene.anchors.first?.removeFromParent()
            anchor.addChild(entity)
            anchor.position.z = -1.0
            arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        }
        print("Anchors:", arView.scene.anchors.count)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Andy I first copy something incorrectly and tried for the longest time... until I decided to copy it entirely and BOOM IT WORKED!!! THE ARTEXT SAYS "ANDY JAZZ: THE LEGEND"

Comment: The AR text and the screen text all say: "Andy Jazz: Legend" https://imgur.com/sEbo2qe

Comment: This is the most unbelievable RealityKit's text I have ever seen. )))

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are using a binding instead of a let. Binding is only when you need write access which you don’t, so try using a let:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var title: String = "Default Title"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .frame(alignment: .center)
                .font(.title)
            
            TextField("Enter text here:", text: $title)
                .padding([.horizontal], 20)
            
            ARViewContainer(title: title)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}


struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let title: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        ARView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ arView: ARView, context: Context) {
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        let mesh = MeshResource.generateText(title,
                                         extrusionDepth: 0.01,
                                         font: .systemFont(ofSize: 0.12))
        
        let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [UnlitMaterial(color: title == "Default Title" ? .yellow : .cyan)])
        let xHalf = mesh.bounds.extents.x / 2
        entity.position.x -= xHalf
        
      
        arView.scene.anchors.first?.removeFromParent()
        anchor.addChild(entity)
        anchor.position.z = -1.0
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        
        
        print("Anchors:", arView.scene.anchors.count)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how RealityKit works in terms of State changes... without @Binding the UiViewRepresentable/UpdateUIView  won't update ... it's not a webdev situation the views must be updated thus Binding. I've written and re-written an adapted version of this based on AndyJazz's answer, and have since added image changing capabilities into RealityKit textures ( which requires the SwiftUI Coordinator class ... ) and later, SwiftData ... to bind and flow data from a non-RealityKit part of the application...

Comment: I've spent an entire year teaching myself this so I am accidentally knowledgeable about the true 'gotcha' in RealityKit: Updating views and data flow. It's been an UPHILL battle to put together a basic CRUD application ... thanks to KING Andy Jazz who pointed the way forward on his answer here.

Comment: And even when I used SwiftData to share the text data from a non-realitykit view and allow users to pass between AR and regular text, I have kept this set up with State and Binding , on the ARView screen, almost intact. I need to change it later but this is how effective this is. This allows for users to write text from the AR View as well, into the main Swift Data model which houses the text and updates it onto the non AR part of the application.

Comment: Binding is just a pair of get and set closures (which are reference types) which cannot be diffed like values, so it's possible you are benefitting from a side effect of an inefficient body computation. I've seen people using this trick to solve other update problems. It would be better to fix the design so the binding workaround is not needed, I'll have a go and see if I can fix it for you. The usual fix is to make sure @State is being read in the right place so SwiftUI sets up the dependency correctly so body is called. A quick look at your code shows title is not read at all.

Comment: I am referring to Andy Jazz's answer, not my original code. My original code sucked lol of course. Andy's answer is what I have used extensively and have adapted from. If you start from Andy's answer and remove Binding from his code, I am not sure changes will update on the AR View. It's easy to change the text on SwiftUI. What is complicated is changing it into a textEntity in RealityKit and that was the point of the question.

Comment: Ok please take a look at the code I added to the answer.